# Watermark Post is gone

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Sorry, I want to ask, I use the auto watermark plugin, in the media, the watermark is there, but when it's posted on the web, it's gone, but still in the media.

Why is that? Help please

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your cache and refreshing the page? It sounds like your browser has cached the old version of the image.